# Getting javascript - Uncaught TypeError:

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using "numscroller.js" for a counter but Getting 2 javascript Errors - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined at HTMLHeadingElement." - 
**Line no - 40**.

Can anyone help me please with the below code, It's showing the Error is in the line number 40?

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you in Advance.

[image: Attached the SCREENSHOT of Errors.]

Also a working URL - http://bluecrystaluae.com/counter/counter.html

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){

    $(window).on("load",function(){
        $(document).scrollzipInit();
        $(document).rollerInit();
    });
    $(window).on("load scroll resize", function(){
        $('.numscroller').scrollzip({
            showFunction    :   function() {
                                    numberRoller($(this).attr('data-slno'));
                                },
            wholeVisible    :     false,
        });
    });
    $.fn.scrollzipInit=function(){
        $('body').prepend("<div style='position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;width:0;height:0;' id='scrollzipPoint'></div>" );
    };
    $.fn.rollerInit=function(){
        var i=0;
        $('.numscroller').each(function() {
            i++;
           $(this).attr('data-slno',i); 
           $(this).addClass("roller-title-number-"+i);
        });        
    };
    $.fn.scrollzip = function(options){
        var settings = $.extend({
            showFunction    : null,
            hideFunction    : null,
            showShift       : 0,
            wholeVisible    : false,
            hideShift       : 0,
        }, options);
        return this.each(function(i,obj){
            $(this).addClass('scrollzip');
            if ( $.isFunction( settings.showFunction ) ){
                if(
                    !$(this).hasClass('isShown')&&
                    ($(window).outerHeight()+$('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top-settings.showShift)>($(this).offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))&&
                    ($('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))<($(this).outerHeight()+$(this).offset().top-settings.showShift)
                ){
                    $(this).addClass('isShown');
                    settings.showFunction.call( this );
                }
            }
            if ( $.isFunction( settings.hideFunction ) ){
                if(
                    $(this).hasClass('isShown')&&
                    (($(window).outerHeight()+$('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top-settings.hideShift)<($(this).offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))||
                    ($('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))>($(this).outerHeight()+$(this).offset().top-settings.hideShift))
                ){
                    $(this).removeClass('isShown');
                    settings.hideFunction.call( this );
                }
            }
            return this;
        });
    };
    function numberRoller(slno){
            var min=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-min');
            var max=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-max');
            var timediff=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-delay');
            var increment=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-increment');
            var numdiff=max-min;
            var timeout=(timediff*1000)/numdiff;
            //if(numinc<10){
                //increment=Math.floor((timediff*1000)/10);
            //}//alert(increment);
            numberRoll(slno,min,max,increment,timeout);

    }
    function numberRoll(slno,min,max,increment,timeout){//alert(slno+"="+min+"="+max+"="+increment+"="+timeout);
        if(min<=max){
            $('.roller-title-number-'+slno).html(min);
            min=parseInt(min)+parseInt(increment);
            setTimeout(function(){numberRoll(eval(slno),eval(min),eval(max),eval(increment),eval(timeout))},timeout);
        }else{
            $('.roller-title-number-'+slno).html(max);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Please be more specific, what is your code supposed to do, is the element with id `#scrollzipPoint` even existsm check what even `console.log($('#scrollzipPoint').offset());` drops you, debug it, show us what you have tried and what didnt work, what does logs say, etc.. I'm sorry, but people dont want to spend few hours on your problem, you should provide as much as possible.

Comment: I have a doubt on .offset() being available on HTMLElements.

Comment: Sorry Guys, My mistake. I have attached the screenshot of error & also the HTML URL. 
Thank You.

Comment: Your counters work fine for me, I don't get any type of errors. Is there something you are doing that causes the error? Be more specific what isn't working. The timers itself are working fine.

Comment: Hi Comirdc, Counters are working fine. But if check the Chrome - Console - then i can see Errors same as attached screenshot image. ADDED ONE IMAGE TO THE POST. KINDLY CHECK.


Error :-



Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLHeadingElement.<anonymous> (numscroller-1.0.js:48)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.$.fn.scrollzip (numscroller-1.0.js:43)
    at numscroller-1.0.js:10
    at dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)